# QApplication::activeWindow()->windowTitle(); save this info to log every second

Tags: c++, qt

I want to build an app for linux/mac/windows which would log what window is active and when it changes. All data should be written to text file.

I was trying to use this code just to print out active window's title:

QDebug << "Active window: " << QApplication::activeWindow()->windowTitle();

My includes:

QApplication
QWidget
QtGui/QApplication
qmlapplicationviewer.h
QDebug

When I'm calling QApplication::activeWindow()->windowTitle() i get error (Application Output):

The program has unexpectedly finished.

What's wrong?

I'm using Uubuntu 32bit to code and QT Creator v2.4.1 Based on QT 4.8.0 (32bit)

My full code: http://pastebin.com/J97rJv5a

Comment: QApplication::activeWindow() can return NULL if no window is active check that before using the pointer so you do not have an access violation / SEGFAULT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `main` method is executed only once per application launch, if you want to monitor something, you have to do it with [slots and signals mechanism](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/signalsandslots.html). You can achieve that by defining a custom class (alternatively you may subclass QApplication itself) and connecting it to QApplication::focusChanged signal. Every time application focus changes, you will receive a signal. This is `main.cpp`

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QDeclarativeView>

#include "main.h"

Watcher::Watcher(QObject *parent)
  : QObject(parent)
{
}

void Watcher::onFocusChanged(QWidget * old, QWidget * now)
{
    Q_UNUSED(old);

    QWidget * window;
    if (now == 0) {
        window = 0;
    } else {
        window = now->window();
    }

    if (window != 0) {
        qDebug() << window->windowTitle();
    } else {
        qDebug() << "No active window";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* No need for scoped pointer */
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    /* This object will be watching for QApplication::focusChanged signal
     and report that to console */
    Watcher watcher;
    /* We connect QApplication::focusChanged signal to appropriate Watcher's slot */
    QObject::connect(
        &app, SIGNAL(focusChanged(QWidget*,QWidget*)),
        &watcher, SLOT(onFocusChanged(QWidget*,QWidget*)));

    /* Declarative view, it could be any other widget */
    QDeclarativeView view;
    view.setWindowTitle("Test QML Window");
    view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("test.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

and `main.h` will look like this

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#include <QtGui>

class Watcher : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Watcher(QObject *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void onFocusChanged(QWidget * old, QWidget * now);
};

#endif // MAIN_H
```

Comment: Thanks for your full answer :)